# Why are replies to my SMTP-sent gmail messages not threaded?

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib

I'm sending lots of similar emails out via SMTP using the following Python snippet:

```
def send(from_, to, body):
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.ehlo()
  server.login('michael@gmail.com', password)
  msg = '''\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s''' % (from_, to.encode('utf-8'), "Hello", body.encode('utf-8'))
  server.sendmail(from_, to, msg)
  server.quit()
```

These messages are the first messages in a conversation.  Strangley, replies to these messages are **not being threaded** onto the original message's conversation.

A reply comes back as a separate message in my inbox, subject = "Re: Hello", **with no tie to the original**.  (Very occasionally one *will* be threaded properly, which is even weirder.)

I've verified that these (un-threaded) replies have a References: field that refers to the sent mail's Message-ID field, which was autogenerated by GMail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `References:` header.  It contains a chain of the previous `Message-ID:` headers in the thread, and is typically used for threading.  It's usually a good idea to specify the `Message-ID:` yourself, and if you keep track of your previously used ones, you can use them in the `References:` header to enforce threading.

The `Message-ID` should be globally unique.  They're often constructed as something like this, but it's not a requirement.

```
Message-ID: unixtimestamp.somerandomval@sending-hostname
```

Comment: Thanks Michael -- I'll try adding a Message-ID header.  If they're threaded properly, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Michael: thanks.  There are no previous messages: the only message sent via SMTP is the one initiating the conversation.  The rest of the conversation happens in gmail's web interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see that GMail is auto-adding a Message-ID to my message when it is sent over SMTP; whether I explicitly specify one or not doesn't change the outgoing message.  So I don't think that's the culprit.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Furthermore: the replies that are not being threaded correctly DO have a References: header referring to the message ID of the originally sent message.  Might GMail be getting confused by the many similar emails with identical subjects, and giving up on trying to thread properly?